# Dynamics crm 2011 webservice issue

Tags: c#, web-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I have been stuck in a issue that apparently has a small fix but is taking me decades. 
I am a CRM sharepoint dynamics etc noob . However I have managed to do some work in it . 
What I have is a CRM 2011 webservice.

I added the wsdl path in my project as a service reference . That created the Reference.cs class for me .

This is the code that throws in a strange error

```
 ServiceReference1.OrganizationServiceClient obj = new ServiceReference1.OrganizationServiceClient();
 ServiceReference1.Entity entity = new ServiceReference1.Entity();
 entity.LogicalName = "new_project";
 entity.Attributes = new ServiceReference1.AttributeCollection();
 entity.Attributes.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("new_name", "project2"));

 ServiceReference1.OrganizationRequest request = new ServiceReference1.OrganizationRequest() { RequestName = "RetrieveDuplicates" };
 request.Parameters = new ServiceReference1.ParameterCollection();
 request.Parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("BusinessEntity", entity));
 request.Parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("MatchingEntityName", "new_project"));
 request.Parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("PagingInfo", new ServiceReference1.PagingInfo() { PageNumber = 1, Count = 50 }));

 var response= obj.Execute(request);
 obj.Create(entity);
```

The code just checks where the "new_project" entity that we are about to add , is a duplicate of an already added member or not .

Here is the obnoxious exception I receive on obj.execute()

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the
>   message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
>   http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services:ExecuteResult.
>   The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 669. Element
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic:value'
>   contains data from a type that maps to the name
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts:EntityCollection'.
>   The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name.
>   Consider using a DataContractResolver or add the type corresponding to
>   'EntityCollection' to the list of known types - for example, by using
>   the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known
>   types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException
>   for more details.

Please also note that I have attached the KnownAttribute onto the EntityCollection in the reference. cs.

I would be thankful if you could drag me off this mire

Comment: Please add code where you are applying KnownType attribute to EntityCollection

Comment: You should be using the dynamics crm sdk.  It ships an OrganizationServiceProxy and related classes (including Entity) properly KnownTyped.  Sdk has a ton of examples too if I recall correctly.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547453.aspx